# Scriptable Java Transform Spring cloud data flow

Tags: javascript, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to use scriptable transform using javascript to parse json payloads from rabbit. However getting error.

### Stream DEFINITION

rabbit --password='******' --queues=springdataflow-q10 --host=172.24.172.184 --virtual-host=springdataflow --username=springdataflow | scriptable-transform --language=javascript --script='function extract(a)\n{\n var obj = JSON.parse(payload);\n return obj.customerId;\n}\nextract(payload);' | log

### VERSION

The spring cloud data flow version is 1.5.2 and the transform version is.
maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:scriptable‑transform‑processor‑kafka‑10:1.3.1.RELEASE

### ERROR

The stream deploys fine, but on the logs for the transform bit I get a strange error :
docker exec -it dataflow-server tail -f /tmp/spring-cloud-deployer-8103682307576658371/json-parse-js-1538777252915/json-parse-js.scriptable-transform/stdout_0.log
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:73) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:39) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:792) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:736) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2100(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:246) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1025) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_111-internal]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111-internal]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111-internal]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, Please share the full stack trace as the currently posted one above doesn't describe the actual issue.

Comment: Just ran it again unfortunately that is all I am getting in the trace.